# Turtlebot wont move (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, turtlebot, ubuntu, velocity, kobuki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi I'm trying to run some very basic code to move my turtlebot.

i am using ROS Indigo on Ubuntu 14.04.2

I am communicating through MATLAB and I should have everything setup fine(keyword should).

turtlebot ip 192.168.3.139
matlab ip 192.168.3.149

They ping each other fine

My matlab code is this:

```
robot = rospublisher('/mobile_base/commands/velocity')
velmsg = rosmessage(robot)
velmsg.Linear.X = .1
send( robot , velmsg )
```

this is after running rosinit to 192.168.3.139
I get

```
 Initializing global node /matlab_global_node_99074 with NodeURI http://192.168.3.149:5587/
```

I have setup the bashrc as such

```
echo export ROS_HOSTNAME=192.168.3.139 >> ~/.bashrc
echo export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.3.139:11311 >> ~/.bashrc
sudo sh -c 'ROS_HOSTNAME=192.168.3.139 >> /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash'
```

i double checked my bashrc and the env variables are there.

turtlebot moves with keyboard operation fine.

Quick note** I had all this working fine on one laptop, came back to try on a different laptop, didn't work anymore.

I am really not sure what i am missing. i have spent about a week searching for answers.

quick overview of what i do.

```
roscore
```

new terminal

```
roslaunch turtlebot.bringup minimal.launch
```

turtelbot beeps
run the code on matlab
no errors on matlab side

turtlebot doesn't move... it is supposed to lurch forward really quick and stop. I have seen this exact code work(matlab)

when i run rostopic list i see all the commands (including velocity)

I am unsure where to look or find issues. I am assuming the turtlebot isn't receiving the commands?

Any help would be wonderful since i am getting zero errors anywhere

Thanks! (also pretty new to Linux, sorry if i ask for simple clarifications)

---

UPDATE10/12/17:

I just tried to some communications test bewteen the turtlebot and the matlab computer:
I WAS able to recieve scan data from the turtlebot but still NOT able to move the turtlebot

my 'rostopic' list contains

```
/cmd_vel_mux/active 
/cmd_vel_mux/input/navi 
/cmd_vel_mux/input/safety_controller 
/cmd_vel_mux/input/teleop 
/cmd_vel_mux/parameter 
/mobile_base/commands/motor_power 
/mobile_base/commands/motor_power 
/mobile_base/commands/reset_odometry 
/mobile_base/commands/sound 
/mobile_base/commands/velocity
```

(only posted ones that are relevant to movement/question)

after doing some more research i found a hand tool called 'roswtf'

another question made mention of getting similar errors
https://answers.ros.org/question/29983/turtlebot_teleop-not-working-properly/

I also have

```
* /mobile_base_nodelet_manager:
   * /mobile_base/commands/controller_info
   * /mobile_base/commands/external_power
   * /mobile_base/commands/reset_odometry
   * /mobile_base/commands/sound
   * /cmd_vel_mux/input/safety_controller
   * /cmd_vel_mux/input/navi
   * /mobile_base/commands/digital_output
   * /mobile_base/commands/led1
   * /mobile_base/commands/led2
   * /mobile_base/commands/motor_power
```

I have no issue using teleop but I'm wondering if our issues could be related.

Also I found some more info about '/mobile_base/commands/velocity' through matlab.

```
Publisher with properties:

         TopicName: '/mobile_base/commands/velocity'
        IsLatching: 1
    NumSubscribers: 0
       MessageType: 'geometry_msgs/Twist'

ROS Twist message with properties:

    MessageType: 'geometry_msgs/Twist'
         Linear: [1×1 Vector3]
        Angular: [1×1 Vector3]

rostopic info '/mobile_base/commands/velocity'
Type: geometry_msgs/Twist
 
Publishers:
* /mobile_base_nodelet_manager (http://192.168.3.139:41629/)
 
Subscribers:
* /mobile_base_nodelet_manager (http://192.168.3.139:41629/)
```

I'm a little confused by the publisher/subscriber part. Should they have the same IP/port?

also just to calrify, I know that this is a 2way communication setup so the fact that I can receive data and not send it means networking might not be setup properly... although it seems pretty straight forward.

My ROS_HOSTNAME is the ip of the turtlebot
my ROS_MASTER_URI is also the ip of the turtlebot followed by 11311, starts with http://

UPDATE TO THE UPDATE

GOOD NEWS EVERYONE!

So I finally go the turtlebot to move using

```
rostopic pub -r 10 /mobile_base/commands/velocity geometry_msgs/Twist '{linear: {x: 0, y:  0, z: 0}, angular: {x: 0, y: 0, z: 1.0}}'
```

inputting that on the turtlebot laptop made it move.

SO! it must be on the matlab side right? either how its coding, sending message, networking?

I think that should narrow down the troubleshooting.

So i used a different computer and it worked fine....and then i used a different computer from those two and got the same results as the first.....

Any ideas there? (all 3 laptops are setup the same, matlab and all)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/272722/turtlebot-wont-move-(matlab)/) by [Cullen Dubbs](https://answers.ros.org/users/32206/cullen-dubbs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-10-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-10-17**:
It may be a network issue. Can you update your question to include the env variables (`ROS_MASTER`, `ROS_IP` if you're using IP's or `ROS_HOSTNAME` you're using host names) for the computers that you're using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't think that you're publishing to the correct topic (unless that topic is being `remap`ed). From a quick [search in the GitHub repo](https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=cmd_vel&type=) it looks like you should be publishing to the `cmd_vel` topic  or some variant of it. The `/mobile_base/commands/velocity` topic [looks like it's used](https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot/blob/kinetic/turtlebot_bringup/launch/includes/mobile_base.launch.xml#L21) for [muxing](http://wiki.ros.org/yocs_cmd_vel_mux) the navigation commands. If you really are supposed to be publishing to the `/mobile_base/commands/velocity` topic then please update your question with the results of `rostopic list`.

As a side note, please take a look at the [environment variables page on the wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/EnvironmentVariables). If you're going to be using an IP  instead of a host name then you should use `ROS_IP` *not* `ROS_HOSTNAME`. I've also never seen anyone use

```
sudo sh -c 'ROS_HOSTNAME=192.168.3.139 >> /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash'
```

before.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cullen Dubbs](https://answers.ros.org/users/32206/cullen-dubbs/) on 2017-10-11**:
Thanks for the answer! I remember seeing ROS_IP floating around on some wikis, wasnt sure what the difference was between that and ROS_HOSTNAME.

I never considered that i need to use a different topic. I will try that as well! Results to follow soon!

**Comment by [Cullen Dubbs](https://answers.ros.org/users/32206/cullen-dubbs/) on 2017-10-12**:
Ok so here is the 'rostopic list' ,atleast the ones I see on the list that pertain to this problem
/cmd_vel_mux/active
/cmd_vel_mux/input/navi
/cmd_vel_mux/input/safety_controller
/cmd_vel_mux/input/teleop
/cmd_vel_mux/parameter
1

**Comment by [Cullen Dubbs](https://answers.ros.org/users/32206/cullen-dubbs/) on 2017-10-12**:
/mobile_base/commands/motor_power
/mobile_base/commands/motor_power
/mobile_base/commands/reset_odometry
/mobile_base/commands/sound
/mobile_base/commands/velocity
I am going to try some things now, will report soon

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-10-12**:
Please update your question with this information.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2017-10-12**:
Encoding the ROS+HOSTNAME into the setup files in /opt/ros is highly not recommended. That file is versioned inside a debian package should not be mutated. Any changes you make there are subject to changes anytime you change networks and will be lost if the package updates.

**Comment by [Cullen Dubbs](https://answers.ros.org/users/32206/cullen-dubbs/) on 2017-10-13**:
Ya i was following the matlab setup steps for turtlebot and the filesystem they say to run that in didnt exist for me so i assumed it was different for me but im not sure i even need to do that, could that be negativley affecting connectivity?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-14**:
@Cullen Dubbs: probably not, but you should remove what you added to `/opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I GOT THE SOLUTION!!!

Turns out it was the firewall. I needed to allow matlab and on some computers that was already the case.

My final network setup that works was simply

ROS_HOSTNAME= turtlebot IP

ROS_MASTER_URI=turtlebot IP

and thats it!

Matlab autosets everything else for you using 'rosinit'

THANK YOU ALL FOR THE HELP!!!!

---

Originally posted by [Cullen Dubbs](https://answers.ros.org/users/32206/cullen-dubbs/) with karma: 11 on 2017-10-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1